# How to put novalidate attribute in spring form to get error message

Tags: jquery, spring, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have downloaded some bootstrap template, they have did some bootstrap validation, to get validation error message below inputs rather than required alert message they have added novalidate attribute in form tag

This working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wb8vpbc3/16/

How do I get same kind of validation with my spring form

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" method="post" modelAttribute="loginForm" action="authenticateUserLogin">
                    <h3 class="box-title m-b-20">Sign In</h3>
                    <c:if test="${not empty errorMsg}">
                    <p style="color:blue;">${errorMsg}</p> 
                  </c:if>

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                           <!--  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" required="" placeholder="Username"> -->
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">

                             </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" required="" placeholder="Password"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary pull-left p-t-0">
                                <input id="checkbox-signup" type="checkbox">
                                <label for="checkbox-signup"> Remember me </label>
                            </div> <a href="showRecoveryPasswordForm" id="to-recover" class="text-dark pull-right"><i class="fa fa-lock m-r-5"></i> Forgot password?</a> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center m-t-20">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Log In</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group m-b-0">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="showUserSignupForm" class="text-info m-l-5"><b>Sign Up</b></a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
```

Comment: https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-validation-1.html